# Not able to show selected listview item title in textview header in place of Menu

Tags: android, android-widget, android-listview

I am using Textview as a header, but not getting name of selected item using ListView item row,whenever i run my app first listview shows Menu as a Text in Header, because i have given in xml, but in second activity's header i am only getting "title" as a header instead of Selected Item Title, please see where i am missing:-

header.xml

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/actionbar"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="50dip"
android:background="@drawable/header"
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
android:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
android:shadowDx="1"
android:shadowDy="1"
android:shadowRadius="1"
android:text="Menu"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:textSize="25dp"
android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Code:-

```
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
@Override
     protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
                TextView lblTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.actionbar); 
                lblTitle.setText(KEY_TITLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this TextView directly added in your xml? Or have you include it? If it is included you need to look into that layout

```
TextView lblTitle = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.actionbar);
```

Also are you doing this from a asynctask? UI operations always have to be performed from the ui thread. Use this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
      TextView lblTitle = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.actionbar);
      lblTitle.setText(KEY_TITLE);
   }
});
```